# Grouping the files by month and archeiving it in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of files created on different months in my directory.I want to filter out the files created on a certain month and archeive those files using tar functionality. So far the code i have tried is

```
months="Dec-2021"
decfiles=find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec | tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz"
echo $decfiles
```

This above code throws me the error like

```
files.sh: 3: .: Illegal option -n
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I cant seem to figure this out and am a newbie in bash as well. Any help to figure this out would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. +1 for trying before asking. You've got what seems to be a comprehensive answer already so I won't "muddy the waters" by adding another one (yet). Please do update your question if you still have parts that are unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're new, I won't just give you the answer, I'll try to explain how to begin troubleshooting such issues.

First, when you see such issues, try to separate and isolate them to smaller commands.

For instance, instead of directly trying to save the results in a file like you did:

```
decfiles=find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec | tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz"
```

Just try to run the `find` command by itself.

```
find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec | tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz"
```

You'll quickly see:

##### Error #1

```
find: I cannot figure out how to interpret ‘01-Dec-2021 +1 month-1 sec | tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz’ as a date or time
```

Which, if you actually read it, you'll notice that you're running the pipe inside the quotes:

```
"01-$months +1 month-1 sec | tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz"
```

##### Attempt #2

So by now you should hopefully figure out that the find command should be:

```
find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec"
```

Now you you'll get a list of files and directories, which is a beginning. I suggest you only print the **files**, and not the directories, by adding `-type f`.

```
find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f
```

So now we're going somewhere.

Next, I assume you want to try something like that:

```
find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f |tar cz decemberfiles.tar.gz
```

Which will throw:

##### Error #2

```
tar: Refusing to write archive contents to terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

It suggests you're missing `-f` option, so you look at the man pages of `tar` and see that you use `-f ARCHIVE` to provide the name of the archive. You provided the filename, but you didn't say this is the ARCHIVE. So now you try:

##### Attempt #3

```
find . -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f |tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz
```

##### Error #3

Now it will throw new error:

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try 'tar --help' or 'tar --usage' for more information.
```

Why does it say that you're trying to create an empty archive? Again, look at the manual of `tar`, and you'll see that you need to provide the list of files as **arguments**:

```
tar -c [-f ARCHIVE] [OPTIONS] [FILE...]
```

And you were trying to provide the files through pipe to the STDIN of the tar command.
So it needs to be similar to:

```
tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz <file1> <file2> <file3> ...
```

Your list of files is being generated by the `find` command. How do you provide those files to the `tar` command? There are few options that I will not explain, and let you read about them yourself.

###### Option #1

```
tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz $(find ./ -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f)
```

###### Option #2

```
tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz `find ./ -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f`
```

Tip: If you want to understand better what it's doing, try to add echo before the command to see how it will look like (I will not write the output here and let you find it by yourself):

```
echo tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz `find ./ -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f`
```

###### Option #3

Last option, to make you familiarize with the `xargs` command:

```
find ./ -newermt "01-$months -1 sec" -and -not -newermt "01-$months +1 month-1 sec" -type f |xargs tar czf decemberfiles.tar.gz
```

So by now you should at least have the archive, so that's a start. By now you should figure out you have a lot to learn.

You still have some issues to overcome, such as the `decfiles=...` part. Again, try to run a smaller command and see what it says, and search how you can assign output of commands to variable in bash. I won't explain it here since you can google it, but hopefully now you have some better idea on how to start learning bash and overcoming obstacles step by step.

Comment: awesome man..thank you for the explanation